# Codeception: Alternative to `pauseExecution()`? (which is not working anymore)

Tags: php, codeception

In Codeception WebDriver (i.e. acceptance test) this is not working anymore after upgrading to Codeception 2.6:

```php
$I->pauseExecution();
```

Is there an alternative?

Docs of Codeception 2.5: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.5/docs/modules/WebDriver.md#pauseexecution

Answer (score 0):

`pauseExecution()` was removed in favor of the new `pause()` function in Codeception 2.6 in this commit: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commit/edd78659800918118b1a647b0a61977b42160af9#diff-b69c529efcc6368b5c564f8b36665a22

`pause()` features an interactive console, see https://codeception.com/04-24-2019/codeception-3.0.html